# HTML - Center label in a floated div

Tags: html, css

I have a set of floated divs. I have a label in some of these divs. I would like the labels to be vertically centered. I have tried various options suggested on stack overflow questions. However, none of them have helped me so far. Could I request help to get this sorted please?

Here's a sample:

```
<div class="lv_props">
    <div style="float: left"  class="float_d">
        <label>hello 1</label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left"  class="float_d">
        <label>hello 2</label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left"  class="float_d">
        <label>hello 3</label>
    </div>
</div>

label{
    display: inline;
}

.float_div {
    margin-left: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.lv_props {
    padding-left:4%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean *vertical* (i.e. up/down) centering? All answers so far are for *horizontal* (left/right) centering.

Comment: Hello ralph - You're right. People are talking about horizontal centering in their answers. I'm after vertical centerings.Could you please help?

Comment: The div will only be as tall as its content unless it has a height set. If you only have one element inside each div, you can just give the same top and bottom padding to that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for vertical alignment, the `vertical-align: middle;` does not work in the way you expect. An easy solution is to set `line-height` to the same value as `height` on the container. This only works if your labels have a single line like in your example. If your labels have longer text and span more than one line, please provide a better example so we can help you

In your example, all the labels and their container have the same height, so it is hard to demonstrate the effect of vertical alignment. For that reason, I set a height of 100px on the containers, so the solution is to set the `line-height` to 100px too. I added borders just for illustration purpose.

```css
label{
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.float_d {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.lv_props {
  padding-left:4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lv_props">
  <div class="float_d">
    <label>hello 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="float_d">
    <label>hello 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="float_d">
    <label>hello 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to your code was set the `float_d` class to a fixed width. Centered text needs a fixed-width container:

Just add:

```
width: 30%;
```

to your `.float_d` class.

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ct1L4sh/1) here on JSFiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following class.

```
.lv_props {
    padding-left:4%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://codepen.io/fanafazil/pen/bVZMBZ).